# Make every element of an array displaystyle?

Tags: math-mode, arrays

Is there a way to make every element of an `array` be `\displaystyle`? I don't want to do something like `\everymath={\displaystyle}` (or whatever it should be) because I want this for a particular array only. Also, one of the column specifications is `p{5cm}` which makes it text mode. So *that* column shouldn't be `\displaystyle`. (Or rather, the solution shouldn't choke on a text column.

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could insert `\displaystyle` into the column definition, such as

```
\begin{array}{*3{>{\displaystyle}c}p{5cm}}
```

Here I used syntax provided by the `array` package:

- `>{...}` can insert commands before the array element
- `*n{...}` repeats a column definition n times

So in the example we get 3 columns, where all cells have `\displaystyle`, and 1 paragraph column without.

Comment: I really have to learn more about the cool stuff the `array` package can do!

Comment: When I use this inside a beamer frame it gives me errors "illegal character in array arg"...

Comment: I also get "Illegal character in array arg."

Comment: @ahorn Load the `array` package.

Comment: Thank you. Without your comment, I was considering opening a bounty.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `\everymath` inside a scope:

```
{ \everymath={\displaystyle}
  Inside:

  \(
     \begin{array}{cc}
       \frac12 & \frac12
     \end{array}
  \)
}

\medskip
Outside:

\(\frac12\)
```

[image: Output]