# Formula font and line space reduced in array, how to solve this problem?

Tags: equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make every element of an array displaystyle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44407/make-every-element-of-an-array-displaystyle)

I am typing the following equations,

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
L = {C_L}{\left( {\frac{{{k^3}}}{{\varepsilon _h^2}} + C_\eta ^2\frac{{{\nu ^{3/2}}}}{{\varepsilon _h^{1/2}}}} \right)^{{1 \mathord{\left/
 {\vphantom {1 2}} \right.
 \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} 2}}}\\
T = {\left( {\frac{{{k^2}}}{{\varepsilon _h^2}} + C_T^2\frac{\nu }{{{\varepsilon _h}}}} \right)^{{1 \mathord{\left/
 {\vphantom {1 2}} \right.
 \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} 2}}}\\
{T_{\lim }} = \frac{{0.6}}{{\sqrt 6 {C_\mu }\varsigma \sqrt {{S_{ij}}{S_{ij}}} }}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
```

However, I found the line spacing and fonts in the formula is "automatically" reduced and resized by the compiler. :(

Could anyone tell me how to normalize it? Thanks

Comment: In addition to methods of making arrays be displaystyle it is generally better to use `align` from the amsmath package rather than using array to align equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should yield some improvement; it requires use of `amsmath`:

```
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned}
L &= {C_L}{\left( {\frac{{{k^3}}}{{\varepsilon _h^2}} + C_\eta ^2\frac{{{\nu ^{3/2}}}}{{\varepsilon _h^{1/2}}}} \right)^{{1 \mathord{\left/
 {\vphantom {1 2}} \right.
 \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} 2}}}\\
T &= {\left( {\frac{{{k^2}}}{{\varepsilon _h^2}} + C_T^2\frac{\nu }{{{\varepsilon _h}}}} \right)^{{1 \mathord{\left/
 {\vphantom {1 2}} \right.
 \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} 2}}}\\
{T_{\lim }} &= \frac{{0.6}}{{\sqrt 6 {C_\mu }\varsigma \sqrt {{S_{ij}}{S_{ij}}} }}
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
```